# Зачем используется [].forEach.call()?

Tags: javascript, массивы

Наткнулся на такой пример:

```
function startGame(){
   var shuffledCards = shuffle(cards);
   for (var i= 0; i < shuffledCards.length; i++){
      [].forEach.call(shuffledCards, function(item){
         deck.appendChild(item);
      });
   }
}

const card = document.getElementsByClassName('card');
const cards = [...card];
```

Почему не написать так:

```
function startGame(){
    var shuffledCards = shuffle(cards);
    shuffledCards.forEach(item => deck.appendChild(item));
}
```

1. Зачем там цикл for?
2. Зачем используется

   ```
    [].forEach.call(shuffledDeck, function), когда можно shuffledDeck.forEach(function)?
   ```

Переменные cards и shuffledCards это уже и так массивы.

Comment: Вообще не пойму почему вопрос дубликатом пометили? Я тоже не сразу въехал почему `for` используется в купе с `[].forEach`. И обратите внимание что `NodeList` распаковали `const cards = [...card];`.

Comment: Судя по смешению подходов `[...card]` и `[].forEach.call` данный код мог быть написан разнымми людьми\в разное время. Без полноценнго примера нельзя сказать наверняка, что и зачем было написано. @РустамГимранов вполне возможно, что для обратной совместимости)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, скорее всего, никакой магии: код переписывали на новый лад, да не допереписали )

Comment: Это из статьи https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-build-a-memory-matching-game-in-javascript

Comment: @РустамГимранов самое смешное, что приведенного кода нету в статье :-)

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko как же нет, раздел 1. Shuffing Cards 2-й сниппет

Comment: @illia_maksymov Где там код `const card = document.getElementsByClassName('card');
const cards = [...card];`?

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko, первый сниппет выше 1-го раздела, только там let вместо const, это я поменял let на const

Comment: @illia_maksymov покаэите на скриншоте, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko, http://joxi.ru/1A538aViDJOp1m, первый сниппет в статье